# Getting navigation.state.params for initial route

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-redux, react-navigation

I have a drawer navigator each drawer entry is a stack navigator.
essentially all I want to do is use the same stack navigator in two drawer entries, but pass a prop to it so it can do things differently.

I'm using redux so the navigation actions go through my Navigation Reducer function. What I'm trying to do is set the navigation.state.params with something when the drawer gets navigated. Simple enough with the default case in my nav reducer being:

```
    default:
  if (action.routeName == "MyProposalNavigator")
  {
    console.log("navRed MyProposalNavigator");
    var routeWithParams= {
     routeName: 'MyProposalNavigator',
     params: { listtype: MY_PROPOSALS}
    };
    const navigateAction = NavigationActions.navigate(routeWithParams);
    nextState = AppNavigator.router.getStateForAction(
      navigateAction,
      state
    );

  } else {
    // all other "type":"Navigation/NAVIGATE"
    nextState = AppNavigator.router.getStateForAction(action, state);
  }
  break;
```

So inside MyProposalNavigator (which is a StackNavigator) - the initial route is ProposalList. Inside ProposalList when I look for navigation.state.params it's undefined. I suspect that the params are not being passed from the StackNavigator to the ProposalList (screen).

I've used the same method with 'params' on another navigation action and it works fine.

I notice that my navigation reducer doesn't get a navigation action for the initialRoute (ProposalList) - so I can't modify the state on that action - which is what I suspect I actually have to do.

So my question is: How to I set navigation.state.params on the initialRoute of a StackNavigator if that navigation action doesn't pass through my navigation reducer?